# Logical operation on data frame of column 2 returning corresponding column 1 value

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

I have a data frame described below and i want to do some logical analysis on the column
named "a".For each ID i have starting value (@t=o) of "a" called baseline.
I am entering into "a" data and checking whether my a>=baseline.If TRUE then go next.
If FALSE then write down the corresponding t value (when you observe first FALSE).
like that if you dont find TRUE then note down the last corresponding value of t...
To understand better i have given following example.
Can you suggest me some suitable way of this.I do not want to use FOR loop.

```
ID  t  a    To understand column
 1   0  12   TRUE  (this a value is baseline for ID=1)
 1   5  16   TRUE  (a>=baseline)
 1   10 18   TRUE   ...so on..
 1   15 20   TRUE (upto here we found all TRUE so take this last corresponding t value)
 2   0  16   TRUE   (this a value is baseline for ID=2)
 2   2  19   TRUE 
 2   4   9   FALSE  (here a>=16 is not satisfied)So take that corresponding t value
 2   6  25   TRUE 
 3   0  50   TRUE 
 3   3  52   TRUE 
 3   6  55   TRUE 
 3   8  49   FALSE (here a>=50 is not satisfied)so take that corresponding value


 ID=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)
 t=c(0,5,10,15,0,2,4,6,0,3,6,8)
 a=c(12,16,18,20,16,19,9,25,50,52,55,49)
 data= data.frame(ID,t,a)


#Desired Output (by using Stack/split by ID or **some other possible ways**..)
ID   t
1  15 (#We didn't find FALSE so took the last t element of that ID )
2   4 (#wherever we find first FALSE take the corresponding value of t at that ID)
3   8 (#same like ID=2 but to explain the example it happened at last t element of that ID)
```

Comment: can you post some sample data to work with and what you've tried

Comment: @rawr can you please take a look ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still very much a beginner at R, but here's one fairly simple version that can surely be cleaned up;

```
> do.call("rbind", lapply(split(data, ID), 
    function(x) {
        z = x['a']>=cummax(x['a']); z[length(z)]=FALSE; head(x[!z,],1)
    }
))

  ID  t  a
1  1 15 20
2  2  4  9
3  3  8 49
```

What it does is basically split the frame by ID, and for each resulting frame finding the row with the first decreasing value in the series (falling back to the last if none match) and re-merging the frames.